# angular.forEach and objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, asynchronous, foreach

**The Problem:**

I'm doing (what I think is but maybe isn't) a simple `angular.forEach` over an array then using `$resource` to make a call based on each value returned. The result of each call is an object, as I'm expecting. But, I can't get these objects to join harmoniously in the way the [angular.forEach documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.forEach) demonstrates.

But first, some code that works and then a look at code that fails.

**Works**:

```
var uniqueIds = {};
angular.forEach(object, function(key, value){
    this.push(key.uniqueIds);
}, uniqueIds);
console.log(uniqueIds)
// uniqueIds equals the expected array
```

**Fails**

Here's where things get tricky. Now, in the next sample, inside the `angular.forEach` is a `$resource` call.

```
angular.forEach(array, function(index){
    Resource.query({id:index}, function(result){
        console.log(result)
        // returns the expected object, 
        // but, as expected, I can't access the object outside the async call
    });
    console.log(result);
    // result is undefined
 });
```

Given the async-ness, it seems a promise could solve the problem. But it doesn't--I'm really still inside the async call. Nor does assigning `result` to `$scope` work. In short, I can't seem to get a value outside the `Resource.query`.

**What Do I Need To Happen?**

I need the returned object of each `$resource` call to add up to one object (using angular.extend? I've tried that) in the same way the `angular.forEach` created an array. I've tried many different approaches, most all based on answers for general async questions asked here, but so far to no avail. I'm positive it's an issue with getting the value out of the `$resource` call, but how to do that in this case I'm a bit baffled.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var promises = [];

angular.forEach(array, function(index) {
  promises.push(Resource.query(...));
});

$q.all(promises).then(function(result1, result2, result3 ...) {
  // do stuff with result1, result2 ... or
  // var results = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
});
```

Comment: I'm floored by how elegant and simple this solution is. Exactly what I needed.

Comment: That's AngularJS for you, @jodytate :)

Comment: Using `foreach` to build an array seems redundant when you can simply use Array.map to map each element (or index) to an array of promises, which you can then pass to `$q.all`

Answer (score 4):

Angular [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) has very good example for this

```
var values = {name: 'misko', gender: 'male'};
var log = [];
angular.forEach(values, function(value, key) {
    this.push(key + ': ' + value);
 }, log);
```

Answer (score 2):

`.query` returns an array reference which is being filled with data when the xhr is completed.
Since, probably `id` is a unique identifier, the query will return array with a single element, thats why I would suggest you to use `.get` instead.

Anyway, if you still intent to use `.query` you can do something like:

```
var arrays = [];
angular.forEach(array, function(index){
    arrays.push(Resource.query({id:index}, function(result){
        console.log(result)
        // returns the expected object, 
        // but, as expected, I can't access the object outside the async call
    }));
    console.log(result);
    // result is undefined
});

$scope.$watch(function () {
    return arrays;
}, function (arrays) {
    angular.forEach(arrays, function (array) {
       angular.forEach(array[0], function () {
          //Do something with the object fields
       });
    });
});
```

As you can see the code looks pretty bad...

In order to achieve better result you can use:

```
var objects = [];
angular.forEach(array, function(index){
    objects.push(Resource.get({ id:index });
});

$scope.$watch(function () {
    return objects;
}, function (objects) {
    angular.forEach(objects, function (obj) {
       angular.forEach(obj, function () {
          //Do something with the object fields
       });
    });
});
```

Even better will be if you let AngularJS to do the `$watch` by assigning `objects` to a `$scope` property.