# $q.all and creation of a new object not working in the view

Tags: angularjs, promise, q

I'm having difficulty with `$q.all` not resolving in AngularJS. I may not be describing things correctly, but this is at least the scenario.

**The Service**

```
app.factory('myService', function($http){
    return {
        get: function () {
            return $http.get('http://localhost:8001/');
        }
    };
});
```

**In the Controller**

```
angular.forEach(array, function(item){
    promises.push({foo:myService.get(), bar: item});
});
$q.all(promises).then(function(results){
    $log.info(results);
    $scope.results = results;
});
```

In the view, anything taking values from `bar` displays correctly. Anything, however, taking its values from `foo` is blank. In the console `bar` is an inspectable object as you'd expect. But `foo` is still a promise. It has all the methods a promise would, but no data associated.

So, somehow, $q.all isn't resolved by the time the results are applied to the `$scope`. And why, I'm not sure.

I'll note that I've based what I'm doing above somewhat on what's here: [angular.forEach and objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21388741/angular-foreach-and-objects)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[$q.all](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q) is expecting an array of promises. try something like this:

```
angular.forEach(array, function(item){
    var foo = myService.get();
    var bar = myOtherService.get();
    promises.push(foo); 
    promises.push(bar);  
});

$q.all(promises).then(function(results){
    $log.info(foo);
    $log.info(bar); 
});
```

**UPDATE**

if you need you could nest multiple $q.all

```
angular.forEach(array, function(item){

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $q.all([myService.get(), myOtherService.get()]).then(function(results){
      deferred.resolve({foo:results[0], bar: results[1]});
    });  

    promises.push(deferred.promise);

});

$q.all(promises).then(function(results){
    $log.info(results);
});
```

Comment: This works, but not quite how I need it to. This creates eight objects rather than four with two inner objects.

Comment: Check the updated answer. You could nest multiple $q.all to give the format needed

Comment: That did it! (There's an extraneous ; in the update at `.promise;);`, but the editor wouldn't let me fix only one character at a time)

Comment: little typo, I removed that extra semicolon

Answer (score 0):

Can you make a plnkr?  Also your array of "promises" aren't promises but a custom object where one property is the promise and the other is something else.  If you want to make a promise hash it should look like this:

```
var promises = {};
angular.forEach(array, function(item){
    promises[item.foo] = item.promise;
});

$q.all(promises).then(...
```